# Texture displacement to all sides of an objects with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, displacement

When I use a default Texture Noise in blender it looks evenly on the cube.
But when using a downloaded one the texture is not applied equally on the sides as well as on the top and bottom sides.

How can I handle this using geometry nodes?

[image]

(*the cube on the left is made with the modifier while the cube on the right is made with GN*)

Can I also change the coordinates the position and size of the texture?

Comment: you need you use a uv map or something for the vector input of the texture.

Comment: or set the texture node to box project

Comment: hello @shmuel i don't want to be a bother but could you explain with more details and screenshots if possible? i'm new to this geo nodes stuff.